# modifying hibernate file to match my need

Tags: java, hibernate, file, hibernate-search

I need to increase the sleep time in the java class FSMasterDirectoryProvider.java which is in hibernate-search-engine-4.5.3.Final.jar. I tried getting the sources jar for the same version and recompile and package it by modifying the sleep time. I used jdk1.7 while recompilation and packaging. But when I deployed that jar, I started getting different type of exceptions. Is there any other way to get the source and modify it? and where can I get all the dependency list which will be require for building and packaging.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to recompile Hibernate Search to change the refresh period, just use the `hibernate.search.default.refresh` property and set it to the number of seconds you want.

---

Regarding your question... I wouldn't do such a thing myself if there was any other way to solve the issue (in particular, the one I gave above, or upgrading to a more recent version of Hibernate Search, since yours is really old).

That being said, if you must... The source for Hibernate Search 4.5.3 is available on GitHub: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/tree/4.5
Instructions to build it are provided in the README: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/tree/4.5#building-from-source

Good luck.